# Django form is still full after sign up

Tags: python, django, forms, view, django-class-based-views

I have an app in django 1.11. Below is the view with the form where the user can sign up for the event, after saving he gets a message about the details - on the same page, at the same url. But, after saving the form is completed and after pressing F5 the next saving is performed. How can I avoid this?

I think something with the form_valid method is wrong.

```
class EventDetailView(DetailView, CreateView):
    model = models.Event
    form_class = forms.ParticipantForm
    context_object_name = 'event'
    template_name = 'events/event_detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('events:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs['slug'], 'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['registered_event'] = context['event']
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: `DetailView` and `CreateView` weren't designed to be used together like that, you might get some odd behaviour. There's a section [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview) about doing form processing on a `DetailView` that you might find useful.

Answer (score 2):

After a successful form submission, you should redirect to prevent duplicate submissions.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Remember to add the import

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```

Comment: I tried this solution and isn't working for me because under `context['registered_event']` I have message for user. After reload I do not have this message @alasdair

Comment: Redirecting after a successful post is the standard approach, if you don't do this then it's much trickier to prevent duplicate submissions. If you want to add a message you could look at the [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) framework or store the message elsewhere like the session or querystring.

Answer (score 0):

use flash message to show messages.

```
from django.contrib import messages as flash_messages

flash_messages.success(request, "Your Message Here")
```

and refresh page.